# SQL Server table optimal indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a very specific question, this is part of a job interview test.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Teszt
(
    Id              INT NOT NULL
   , Name           NVARCHAR(100)
   , [Description]  NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , Value          DECIMAL(20,4)
   , IsEnabled      BIT
)
```

And these selects:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Teszt 
WHERE Id = 10

SELECT Id, Value 
FROM Teszt 
WHERE IsEnabled = 1

SELECT [Description] 
FROM Teszt 
WHERE Name LIKE '%alma%'

SELECT [Description] 
FROM Teszt 
WHERE Value > 1000 AND IsEnabled = 1

SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Teszt 
WHERE IsEnabled = 1
```

The question is, where on this table should I put indexes to optimize the performance of the above queries. No other info on the table was provided, so my answer will contain the general pro/contra arguments for indexes, but I'm not sure regarding the above queries.

My thoughts on optimizing these specific queries with indexes:

Id should probably have an index, looks like the primary key and it is part of a where clause;

Creating one on the Value column would also be good, as its part of a where clause here;

Now it gets murky for me. for the Name column, based on just the above queries, I probably shouldn't create one, as it is used with LIKE, which defeats the purpose of an index, right?

I tried to read everything on indexing a bit column (isEnabled column in the table), but I couldn't say it's any clearer to me, as the arguments are wildly ranging. should I create an index on it? should that be filtered? should it be part of a separate index, or just part of one with the other columns?

Again, this is all theoretical, so no info on the size or the usage of the table.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Are all columns besides `Id` `nullable`?

Comment: my guess is yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index on a bit column is generally not recommended.  The following discussion applies not only to bit columns but to any low-cardinality value.  In English, "low-cardinality" means the column takes on only a handful of values.

The reason is simple.  A bit column takes on three values (if you include `NULL`).  That means that a typical selection on the column would return about a third of the rows.  A third of the rows means that you would (typically) be accessing every data page.  If so, you might as well do a full table scan.

So, let's ask the question explicitly:  When is an index on a bit index useful or appropriate?

First, the above argument does not work if you are always looking for `IsEnabled = 1` and, say, 0.001% of the rows are enabled.  This is a highly selective query and an index could help.  Note:  The index would not help on `IsEnabled = 0` in this scenario.

Second, the above argument argues in favor of a *clustered* index on the bit value.  If the values are clustered, then even a 30% selectivity means that you are only reading 30% of the rows.  The downside is that updating the value means moving the record from one data page to another (a somewhat expensive operation).

Third, a bit column can constructively be part of a larger index.  This is especially true of a clustered index with the bit being first.  For instance, for the fourth query, one could argue that a clustered index on `(IsEnabled, Value, Description)` would be the optimal index.

To be honest, though, I don't like playing around with clustered indexes.  I prefer that the primary key be the clustered index.  I admit that performance gains can be impressive for a narrow set of queries -- and if this is your use case, then use them (and accessing enabled rows might be a good reason for using them).  However, the clustered index is something that you get to use only once, and primary keys are the best generic option to optimize `join`s.

Comment: Thanks very much Gordon!

Comment: Note: you can not create a clustered index with a `(max)` length column.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon! 
Just some follow-up questions. At which percentage of the rows having 1 value could an index be worth it? You mention 0.001% but that seems like an extreme to me. Can you elaborate on the query optimizers behaviour here regarding accessing the data pages? At which percentage of the rows can I say that it won't do a full table scan? Sorry If my questions are naive, I never had to dig this low before. Also, do you agree with my other observations in the original post? Thanks again!

Comment: @TamásPásztor . . . If you want to learn about indexing, read the documentation for different databases on adding indexes (such as MySQL, SQL Server, and Postgres).  They work pretty similarly across indexes.  Then, play around with different indexes on different columns and queries.  If you don't have a set of data, the companion page to *Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel* has appropriate data for such investigations.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the detail about on how to create index from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

As you said there are pros and cons using index.

**Pros:** Select query will be faster
**Cons:** Insert query will be slower

**Conclusion:** Add index if your table has less `INSERT` AND most `SELECT` operation.

`In which Column I should consider adding index?` This is really a very good question. Though I am not the DB expert, here are my views:

1. Add index on your primary key column
2. Add index on your join column [inner/outer/left]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: on `Id` and `IsEnabled`
(despite the controversy about indexing on `BIT` field; and `Id` should be primary key)

Generally, to optimize the performance, indexes should be on fields, where there is `WHERE` or `JOIN`. (Under the hood) To make the selection, the db server looks for index, and if not found -- creates one on-the-fly in the memory, which takes time, hence performance degradation.

As Bhuwan noted, indexes are "bad" for `INSERT`s (keep that in mind for the whole picture when designing a database), but there are just `SELECT`s in the example privided.

Hope you passed the test :)

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

tldr: I will probably delete this later, so no need!

---

My answer to this job interview question: **"It depends."** ... and then I would probably spend too much of the interview talking about how terrible the question is.

The problem is that this is simply a bad question for a "job interview test". I have been poking at this for two hours now, and the longer I spend the more annoyed I get.

1. With absolutely **no information** on the content of the table, we can not guarantee that this table is even in the first normal form or better, so we can not even assume that the only non nullable column `Id` is a valid primary key.
2. With no idea about the content of the table, we do not even know if it needs indexes. If it has only a few rows, then the entire page will sit in memory and whichever operations you are running against it will be fast enough.
3. With no cardinality information we do not know if a `value > 1000` is common or uncommon. All or none of the values could be greater than 1000, but we do not know.
4. With no cardinality information we do not know if `IsEnabled = 1` would mean 99% of rows, or even 0% of rows.

I would say you are on the right track as far as your thought process for evaluating indexing, but the trick is that you are drawing from your experiences with indexes you needed on tables before this table. Applying assumptions based on general previous experience is fine, but you should always test them. In this case, blindly applying general practices could be a mistake.

---

> The question is, where on this table should I put indexes to optimize the performance of the above queries. No other info on the table was provided

If I try to approach this from another position: Nothing else matters except the performance of these five queries, I would apply these indexes:

```
create index ixf_Name on dbo.Teszt(Name)
include (Id)
where id = 10;

create index ixf_Value_Enabled on dbo.Teszt(Value) 
include (Id)
where IsEnabled = 1;

create index ixf_Value_gt1k_Enabled on  dbo.Teszt(Id)
include (description,value,IsEnabled)
where Value > 1000 and IsEnabled = 1;

create index ixf_Name_Enabled on dbo.Teszt(Id)
include (Name, IsEnabled)
where IsEnabled = 1;

create index ixf_Name_notNull on dbo.Teszt(Name)
include (Description)
where Name is not null;
```

[image]

---

Also, the `decimal(20,4)` annoys me because this is the least amount of data you can store in the 13 bytes of space it takes up. `decimal(28,4)` has the same storage size and if it could have been `decimal(19,4)` then it would have been only 9 bytes. Granted this is a silly thing to be annoyed about, especially considering the table is going to be wide anyway, but I thought I would point it out anyway.